# c++ in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm learning C++ but I have seen that Visual Studio has Visual C++. I searched about the difference but I haven't found anything satisfying.
The only thing I found was, that Visual C++ is a version of C++ but with more libraries. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

So I have two questions:

1. What's the difference between C++ and Visual C++?
2. And can I write normal C++ in Visual Studio? If I can't write normal C++ in Visual Studio, where do I write it the best in.

I want to try to make some small games.

Comment: One is a formal programming language, the other a commercial software product, manufactured by Microsoft, claiming to implement that language.

Comment: @WhozCraig Let's just keep it at _claiming_ .

Comment: Hey now, Visual C++ is been getting better nowadays and more conforming! Most satisfying for small games as you stated your purpose. Make sure you use the latest installment (VS2015 Update 2/3)!

Comment: @DeiDei I actually concur with that. Their 2013 release was *horrible*, but they really have stepped up their game since. Still not outstanding, but much, *much* better than just a couple years ago. (Yeah, I'm a clang guy, in case it wasn't obvious).

Comment: Fair enough, 2015 was decent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ is a programming language and Visual C++ is a Microsoft's C++ compiler.

Visual C++: less portable, but has specialized libraries which may make you stick with Windows.

Comment: @yentepaternotte Yes, yes you can.